# Grand Total is wrong in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table in Google Data Studio with the following data:

```
Date    Users
1-Mar-18    616
2-Mar-18    632
3-Mar-18    550
4-Mar-18    567
5-Mar-18    688
6-Mar-18    1,844
7-Mar-18    788
8-Mar-18    2,153
9-Mar-18    1,469
10-Mar-18   554
11-Mar-18   448
12-Mar-18   861
13-Mar-18   1,578
14-Mar-18   823
15-Mar-18   628
16-Mar-18   556
17-Mar-18   292
18-Mar-18   311
19-Mar-18   635
20-Mar-18   1,966
21-Mar-18   1,111
22-Mar-18   748
23-Mar-18   610
24-Mar-18   366
25-Mar-18   359
26-Mar-18   720
27-Mar-18   2,103
28-Mar-18   879
29-Mar-18   664
30-Mar-18   562
31-Mar-18   272
```

If you sum the "Users" you will come up with 26353 as a total. However, if you check the "Show summary row" box on the "Data" tab for the table, the "Grand Total" for users is listed as 20,997.

Furthermore, if I create a scorecard with "Users" as the metric over the same date period, I get 20,997 as the total number of Users. However, if I reduce the date period to cover any single day, I will get the same value value for users for that day as I see in the table (e.g. A scorecard on Users with a date range from March 1 to March 1 will show 616 Users).

I am not sure where this difference is coming from, and I'm not sure which number to trust.

Comment: I just did a quick test and it shows 26353 as expected ([image](https://imgur.com/a/96sji)). Can you provide a screenshot or more info?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your breakdown dimension (date). Google Analytics does its best to deduplicate users. So, if you're looking at the whole month, it will tell you that you had 20,997 users. But if you add a specific day to the mix and some of those users came back multiple times, then you'll necessarily have a higher number. Each of those users is only counted once for the aggregate number, but when split out by day, they may be listed several times.