# Grand totals row not summing in Google Data Studio

Tags: sum, report, looker-studio

Well, I'm absolute newbie in Google Data Studio, but for any reason, my grand totals rows is not working.

I'm learning to use this tool, and I made an easy table with just countries and sessions.

[image]

Piece of Cake. Now I just want to add a total row where it sums all sessions. That's all. I activated option *Show Summary Row* but it shows nothing.

Thing's I've done and not worked:

1. Update and refresh
2. Changed time period and tried different dates just in case.
3. Delete and create again full table.
4. Checked connection. I get data and the data is right, I just cannot sum it.
5. Changed size and format of table, just in case it where a problems or margins or font color.

And I know it can be done, because different sources. I've read this question here:

[Grand Total is wrong in Google Data Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662599/grand-total-is-wrong-in-google-data-studio)

But it did not help. In that question, a user posted an image in the comments:

[image]

As you can see, he managed to get what I'm trying to do.

So I must be doing something wrong, and I do not why.

**UPDATE 2:** If I apply a filter, I get no totals. You can see my config in the right side of image.

[image]

Can anybody give me a clue of how to make a grand totals row in Google Data Studio?

Thanks

Comment: Strange one. Is there anything in the "sesiones" data (strings, nulls, different format, etc) that might be causing the problem? If you filter the data to just Spain for example, does it still not create the total?

Comment: Hi @Bobbylank. *sesiones* means sessions (visits). No nulls, string or format changes. I just select that metric when setting up the table. About filtering, check updated question. It did not work, and in the image you can see how I have set it up

Comment: Sounds like a bug. It should be a case of selecting that tick box. Strangely, I looked at an existing table I have with totals and when I unticked the box and then ticked again, the totals didn't reappear and disappeared off another table on the page (like your example). They did reappear eventually with some refreshing of the data and page but seems like there's something wrong with them.

Comment: Hi @Bobbylank. You were 100% right. I did nothing, but today total rows where working, so it was a bug. Thanks anyways for trying to help me out. If you post that as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. It should be a case of selecting that tick box. Strangely, I looked at an existing table I have with totals and when I unticked the box and then ticked again, the totals didn't reappear and disappeared off another table on the page (like your example). They did reappear eventually with some refreshing of the data and page but seems like there's something wrong with them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a bug I think it part of the design.

I actually just discovered the reason this is happening at least for me, it doesn't actually sum the values in the table, the grand total summary of a table is a sum of whatever the metric being used is not the actual rows shown in the chart. so if you have a dimension (like age / gender) where there is data thresholding applied internally by google but are using a metric such as users you will see the grand total from the metric value without the thresholding applied from the dimension.

Proof below

[image: Image of the table]

You can see the grand total for column 2 is not 953.6 its 453.6 and if i look at a non threshold dimension (country)

[image]

you can see where the 953.6 comes from since the data source supplied to the table uses 80% of all users 1192 * .8 give me 953.6 which is what the grand total is displaying.  Conclusion, the only way this number could be possible is if, when using a threshold dimension for a table with metric there will be a discrepancy since the grand total value is not coming from the table values but rather from metric source data, which will not have the tables dimension applied for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue.  I believe my problem was that the columns I wanted to total were declared as "dimensions" rather than "metrics."  Once I made that change - problem solved.